# Date fails to appear for object on angular front end while it shows up when console.logged in back end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I console log my object in the server (right as it is sent to the front by express) I see the property:

```
creation: Mon Jul 13 2015 16:49:25 GMT-0400 (EDT),
```

However, my console log on the front end shows:

```
creation: null
```

The mongoose model entry is:

```
creation: {type: Date, default: null}
```

I don't even know where to start...I imagine it has something to do with the default being null, but I removed that and the problem is the same...?

Comment: Could you add your front end code ? Did you try to send the request yourself with an HTTP client (HTTP Dev client or Postman on chrome) ?

Comment: Don't forget that unless you are doing some manipulation here then the JSON response being sent to your client is likely containing the "string"  just as your console output is showing. It's usually better to send the timestamp value of the date via `.valueOf()` for easy casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the npm module "mongoose-timestamp"
https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp